# Slick database throttling trait based on the Playframework Slick plugin

Tags: beginner, scala

I implemented a throttled database service trait for wrapping my service code in a future, supplying a slick session and throttling the # of requests in accordance to the length of the thread pool queue.

My main reason for this was to transfer the responsibility for database session / transaction handling away from the controllers into the service layer of the application.

However, since I am fairly new to play and Scala in general and I am working alone, I would really like some input regarding my code. Is it a good practice at all? Am I about to face any negative performance implications? Are there ways to optimize / refactor my code?

The code can also be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8XuH6hQS).

```
import daos.exceptions.TabChordDBThrottleException
import java.util.concurrent.{LinkedBlockingQueue, TimeUnit, ThreadPoolExecutor}
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.db.slick
import play.core.NamedThreadFactory

/**
 * Implement this trait to get a throttled database session Wrapper
 */
trait ThrottledDBService {
  /** Override to use a different Application */
  protected def app = slick.Config.app

  /** Override to use different Databasename*/
  protected def dataBaseName = slick.Config.defaultName

  protected object DBConfiguration {
    private def buildThreadPoolExecutionContext(minConnections: Int, maxConnections: Int) = {
      val threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(minConnections, maxConnections,
        0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable](),
        new NamedThreadFactory("tabchord.db.execution.context"))
      ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(threadPoolExecutor) -> threadPoolExecutor
    }

    val partitionCount = app.configuration.getInt(s"db.$dataBaseName.partitionCount").getOrElse(2)
    val maxConnections = app.configuration.getInt(s"db.$dataBaseName.maxConnectionsPerPartition").getOrElse(5)
    val minConnections = app.configuration.getInt(s"db.$dataBaseName.minConnectionsPerPartition").getOrElse(5)
    val maxQueriesPerRequest = app.configuration.getInt(s"db.$dataBaseName.maxQueriesPerRequest").getOrElse(20)
    val (executionContext, threadPool) = buildThreadPoolExecutionContext(minConnections, maxConnections)
  }

  /** A predicate for checking our ability to service database requests is determined by ensuring that the request
      queue doesn't fill up beyond a certain threshold. For convenience we use the max number of connections * the max
      # of db requests per web request to determine this threshold. It is a rough check as we don't know how many
      queries we're going to make or what other threads are running in parallel etc. Nevertheless, the check is
      adequate in order to throttle the acceptance of requests to the size of the pool.
      @see https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/pull/124
     */
  protected def isDBAvailable: Boolean = {
    val dbc = DBConfiguration
    dbc.threadPool.getQueue.size() < (dbc.maxConnections * dbc.maxQueriesPerRequest)
  }

  /**
   * Wraps the block with a Future in the appropriate database execution context and slick session,
   * throttling the # of request in accordance to the rules specified in the db config and.
   *
   * Terminates the future with a @TabChordDBThrottleException in case of queue overload
   * @param body user code
   * @return Future of the database computation
   */
  protected def throttled[A](body: slick.Session => A):Future[A] = {
    future{
      if(isDBAvailable){
        slick.DB(dataBaseName)(app).withSession {
          s =>
            body(s)
        }
      } else {
        throw new TabChordDBThrottleException("Too many Requests pending in Threadpool")
      }
    }(DBConfiguration.executionContext)
  }

  /**
   * Wraps the block with a Future in the appropriate database execution context and slick transaction,
   * throttling the # of request in accordance to the rules specified in the db config and.
   *
   * Terminates the future with a @TabChordDBThrottleException in case of queue overload
   * @param body user code
   * @return Future of the database computation
   */
  protected def throttledTransaction[A](body: slick.Session => A): Future[A] = {
    throttled {
      s => s.withTransaction {
        body(s)
      }
    }
  }
}
```